# Screen Burn (Yosemite)

Tags: screen

When moving some dock icons around, I noticed screen burn, basically my old dock icons were burnt into the screen, is there a way of fixing this issue? I'm running on a MacBook Pro and Yosemite. Is the burning the type of thing that's going to disappear after a while?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might help

> Create an all-white screen in a graphics application such as
>   AppleWorks or Photoshop, and save it as a JPEG file.
>
> Use this as the image displayed by the screen saver.
>
> Turn the display brightness down (but not off) to preserve backlight
>   bulb life.

Leave the white screen saver on for a while.

or more simple, use the build in "Flurry" screen saver and let it run overnight.